# SQLServer Error: Could not connect to mail server. (The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

My Problem On Database Mail on Sql Server 2008 R2. My Database Mail Work fine upto yesterday since 2 years. But From Today My Database Mail Not Work.

I Restart my Database Server. Reconfigure the Database Mail but still i faced the following error.......

> Message
>   The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (Sending Mail using Account 6 (2017-06-12T16:12:12). Exception Message: Could not connect to mail server. (The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found).

My Mail Account Setting in following...[image]

I tried from Send Test E-mail, See the View Database Mail Log and see the above mention error.

Please help to resolve this issue.....

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Has anything changed on your network? like dns? if you do an nslookup smtp 'server name' do you get a response?

Comment: I contact our IT Department. They Confirm me that, they don't change any network setting like dns. My DNS Work fine but Database Mail Arise Error...@dbajtr

Comment: With no more information no one can help you. Provide more information like how you send the mails, or something helpful.

Comment: I use office365 mail server and the account setting on the above pointed. My credential info are confirmed that this is correct but still face the above error......@UrkoPineda

Comment: Because you use office365 mail then you are connecting to a SMTP server outside of your network (on the internet). So you need to:
1. Make sure port 587 is outbound open in your company firewall from this server.
2. Make sure port 587 is outbound open on the internal fw on the server.
3. Make sure that the IP-range that your server is on is allowed to send mail through office365 portal.
4. Make sure it really is port 587 you are supposed to use. If not then check nr. 1 and 2 again so fw is open for this port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems network related, especially since nothing has changed on the database configuration.

Also make sure, your user has the rights to connect and access the specified mailbox.

Check Firewalls, DNS, IP configuration.

By the way, the configuration for Office365 seems good, that's the one I use for my servers ;)